# Can some one help me to understand this question?

Tags: javascript

I was doing a test and one of the questions was as follow:

True or false?

**A stream fires finish event when all data has been flushed to underlying system.**

To be honest, I still don't even understand the question.
Can some one give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

They mean this type of stream:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)

The data 'being flushed' means that it is sent to the receiver of the stream (usually one end will send data, the other end will receive it)

This means that the stream will 'finish'(stop sending data) when it has sent all the data it needs to send to the one (or more) points that are waiting for data from it.

Comment: Note that data being flushed through the stream doesn't necessary mean that the stream is done sending data. This only means that the current stream buffer holding the data is complete end ready for sending. For example if a sender reads a file and streams it to a client, you could flush the buffer whenever you want. You can choose to flush for each new character read, each line read or even flush after the whole file is loaded into the buffer.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGwIg.jpg

nodejs network test piped to cmatrix hitting remotes